# Cannot put where into query

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to do this task:

> Find total amount of all orders for each customer, sort customers by
>   the value from maximum amount to minimum and show customers from 40 to
>   50 position in the result. Only one query.

I'm training on Northwind sample database. My query:

```
;WITH MyCte AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(OD.UnitPrice*OD.Quantity*(1-OD.Discount)) DESC) Number
        , O.CustomerID
        , SUM(OD.UnitPrice*OD.Quantity*(1-OD.Discount)) TotalAmount     
    FROM [Order Details] OD
    RIGHT JOIN Orders O ON OD.OrderID = O.OrderID
    GROUP BY CustomerID
    ORDER BY TotalAmount DESC
)
SELECT 
    Number
    , CustomerID
    , TotalAmount   
FROM MyCte
WHERE Number BETWEEN 40 AND 50
```

But this doesn't work. May someone help me to put "Where" correctly to this query?

Comment: What means "doesn't work"? can you provide sample data, result and expected result?

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH MyCte AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(OD.UnitPrice*OD.Quantity*(1-OD.Discount)) DESC) Number
        , O.CustomerID
        , SUM(OD.UnitPrice*OD.Quantity*(1-OD.Discount)) TotalAmount     
    FROM [Order Details] OD
    RIGHT JOIN Orders O ON OD.OrderID = O.OrderID
    GROUP BY CustomerID 
)
SELECT 
    Number
    , CustomerID
    , TotalAmount   
FROM MyCte
WHERE Number >= 40 and Number <= 50
```

Main trouble was in Order By in MyCTE table. This query will work.

Comment: If you already knew the solution then why did u post the question here?

Comment: I find this solution from one minute after my post(( Tryed to do this simple task for a 2 ours(